# Click areas break using CSS 3D transforms

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-transforms

On Chrome on OSX, rotating a element in 3D and performing the inverse of the rotation on a child element breaks mouse events on the child including any links. The hit area seems to be misaligned.

The dom structure is:

```html
<div class='test'>
  <div><a href='http://www.google.com'>Click me</a></div>
</div>
```

The above dom structure is also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGY5Q/)

Does anyone know a workaround using the same dom structure that preserves the correct click area?

Comment: In Chrome on Windows, it's not misaligned; it's reduced to the dimension of the test div (that is, a 1px height line in the center of the a

Comment: Same for me on OS X. 1px high.

Comment: This is pretty late :) but did you find a solution for this?
I could see in the jsFiddle the href link was `htpp` instead of `http`. Apart from that things seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

if a DOM element has an event connected to it for example a click element and you rotate it 90 degrees  the element is still at that location but you can't click on it due to it being flat. DOM elements have a zero depth so when you rotate a DOM element 90 degrees you can't see it. if you rotate that same element back you will see it and the click event works. technically the click area works when the element is rotated 90 degrees it just has  a zero point area to be clicked.

For the people that do not believe that the event is still attached test this out and see for your self. The event will stay connected to the element no matter how many transformation you do. It also works for chrome. This also works for links too. The only time an event is removed is when you remove the event or remove the element. transformation will never remove the event or the element.

```js
document.getElementById("testButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("It works");
});
document.getElementById("flipButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.getElementById("testButton").style.webkitTransform == "rotateX(0deg)") {
    document.getElementById("testButton").style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(90deg)";
    document.getElementById("test").style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(90deg)";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("testButton").style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(0deg)";
    document.getElementById("test").style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(0deg)";
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id='testButton'>test button</button>
  <div id='test'>
    <div><a href='http://www.google.com'>Click me</a></div>
  </div>
  <button id='flipButton'>transform button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is an example using your example:

```css
.test {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX( 90deg);
}

.test>* {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX( -90deg);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id='test'>
    <div><a href='http://www.google.com'>Click me</a></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You will notice that it still works. The reason your code is not working is that your href you have `href='htpp://boom'`. The URI `htpp://boom` is not a real address.

There is no such thing as `htpp://` and `boom` is not an address. Your bug in your code has nothing to do with transformation and nothing to do with css. Your bug is not using a real URI.

Comment: What does this add to the previous answer?

Comment: This is not correct, at least, not on Chrome. As per the original post, the click area is not preserved under multiple transforms.

Comment: Mark you are not correct. Please test out a few transformations on a click event and you will see that the event will stay connected to the element. I have updated my post to show a simple example you can test to see that i am right.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickW.McMahon, I've added your example as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aLm5cnv/) however this doesn't provide an answer to my question. Your solution seems to show that reseting the transform at a laters stage does sucessfully maintain the click area, however I need an answer that maintains the click area where the sum of the parent/child transform = 0

Comment: It does not matter if you transform the element or one of its parents. The click even will still not be removed. Based on my answer I clearly state that transforming an element will not remove click events. So based on this statement transforming an element will not remove the click events from child elements as well. My example may show a click on the direct element but simple rap an element in another element transform the parent and you will see that the same is true. transform only transforms nothing more nothing less.

Comment: You will see in my example that transforming the div with the A tag in it has no change to the A tag. The same is true to all attributes of all elements. You will also notice that my example uses your example and shows that it still works.

Answer (score 0):

The `-webkit-transform` property may be functioning properly in displaying either element(s) at `rotateX(90deg)`, or `rotateX(-90deg)`, respectively.

Whereas at `rotateX(90deg)`, the elements would not be expected to be rendered "view-able", or "visible".

The element(s) would be "flattened" along their `X` axis, as it were.

At `rotateX(90deg)` the css is probably `transform` 'ing the element(s) to just that - `90` `deg` (rees) *sic*.

Please see linked jsfiddle, with the css `trasform` property set to `rotateX(45deg)`, and `rotateX(-45deg)`, respectively, to view the prospective `rotateX((n)deg)` progression, at `45deg`.

Again, the `transform` property may simply be attempting to achieve a `true` `90` `deg` (ree) *sic* angle, which, along the `X` axis, might resemble - *if visible* -

`_`

or a "horizon".

`|` - `Y` axis

`_` - `X` axis

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3XpFG/

Edit (update, workarounds)

> You're answer does not mention the clickable area. Also, your demo
>   does not provide a workaround that preserves the click area. –  Mark Lundin

If requirement includes setting `css` property `rotateX()` value to `90deg`, `element` may appear to render similar to `display : none;`, that is, render *virtually* "invisible" on `screen`.
See http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/N6MdE/

Workarounds

1) applicable to both options *a), and b)*, below

html

```
<!-- add `tabindex` attribute to `.test > a`,
     whether `element` rendered "visible", or "invisible",
     pressing `Tab` `key` possible to select `a` `element`,
     possibly add `title` attribute, 
     both `attributes` added for "notification", 
     of `a` `element` ("link") presence at that `position` in `document`,
     still possible to `navigate` to `a` `link`, utilizing `Tab` `key`
-->
<a href='htpp://boom' tabindex="1">Click me</a>
```

a) Render elements at `css` property `rotateX(89deg)`, `rotateX(-89deg)`, respectively, which should `render` the `element`s on `screen`, perhaps preserving at least some of the "effect" such a `ndeg` "rotateX()", offset by `1deg`. jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/bzdak/

```
    .test{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( 89deg );
    height : 50px;
    opacity : 1.0;
}

.test > a{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( -89deg );
}

.test:hover, .test a:hover {  
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(0deg);
     outline : thin solid blue;
     opacity : 1.0;
     cursor : pointer;
}

.test a:link, .test a:active {
    color : #c17d11; 
    font-size : 24px;
}
```

b) Render elements at `css` property `rotateX(89deg)`, `rotateX(-89deg)`, respectively, including `css` property `opacity` value set to `0.9`, which should render the `element`s *virtually* "invisible", similar to a `rotateX(90deg)` rendering (see http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/N6MdE/), adding `css` `:hover` and/or `:active` `pseudo` `elements`, either, or both, for "notification" of `a` `element` ("link") presence at that `position` in `document` jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/De7P6/

```
    .test{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( 89deg );
    display : block;
    height : 50px;
    opacity : 0.9;
}

.test > a{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( -89deg );
}

.test:hover, .test a:hover {  
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(0deg);
     outline : thin solid blue;
    opacity : 1.0;
     cursor : pointer;
}

.test a:link, .test a:active {
    color : #c17d11; 
    font-size : 24px;
}
```

Comment: You're answer does not mention the clickable area. Also, your demo does not provide a workaround that preserves the click area.

Comment: @MarkLundin Note Initially tried to convey that original piece essential rendered `rotate(90deg)` element "invisible", or perhaps even less than `1px`, though not certain if that entirely possible. What would be the requirement for the dimensions of the `click`, or `click`able area?